# Контроль версий для больших файлов

Tags: git, svn, миграция

Мигрирую с SVN в GIT.

В SVN было большое дерево, которое редко кто выкачивал целиком - это решилось множеством мелких репозитариев в git.

Но осталась одна проблема - большие файлы которые требуют контроля версий (графика, бинарники).

1. git-у от них плохо
2. clone такого репозитария будет делаться
   несколько часов и кому он нужен в таком объёме
3. все привыкли к тортиле

Посоветуйте систему контроля версий для них, сочетающую возможности SVN

- хранит только изменения
- на рабочей машине только последняя ревизия и рабочий каталог
- удобный интерфейс пользователя
- возможность работать из командной строки

и git

- быстрая и нормальная работа с ветвлением
- возможность работать без прямого доступа в репозитарий или иметь несколько зеркал центрального репозитария.

Comment: SourceTree - последние два пункта точно есть.

Comment: @ПавелВайсберг: SourceTree это клиент, а не система контроля версий.

Comment: нельзя сочетать несочетаемое... 2 и 6 вместе не живут.

Comment: Обычно в таких случаях бинарники хранят в каком-нибудь внешнем хранилище, а в репозитории только ссылки на них. После чекаута ветки пользователь вызывает скриптик, который скачивает бинарники нужной версии.

Comment: Если кто-нибудь своим ответом-таки решил вашу проблему (даже если это ваш ответ), то не поленитесь отметить ответ "галочкой" (рядом со "стрелочками" у ответов), чтобы он не висел в списке неотвеченных :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://about.gitlab.com/2015/02/17/gitlab-annex-solves-the-problem-of-versioning-large-binaries-with-git/

Похоже самое правильное решение в моём случае.
спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле у вас остается не так много вариантов: либо вы пробуете на [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/), который не слишком хорошо подходит для хранения бинарных файлов, например, но зато дает хорошую историю веток и [хранит ревизии инкрементально, а не сжатыми слепками](https://habrahabr.ru/post/168675/), либо все-таки используете GIT. 
А для "удобного интерфейса пользователя" воспользуйтесь клиентом для системы контроля версий, например, [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), либо GitHub, если вы решите остаться на Git'е.

---

А вообще, по поводу выбора между Git и Mercurial уже подымалась [тема ранее](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837/what-is-the-difference-between-mercurial-and-git).